# How to force a view of meta data as Google or Bing sees it?

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, bing-webmaster-tools, bingbot, hacked-site

I'm having an extremely peculiar problem with a site (WordPress) that just suddenly started exhibiting an issue where Japanese is showing up for all the metadata in Google and Bing - only:

Google:

[image: japanese meta in Google]

Bing:

[image: and in bing]

When I view this site's meta data in Chrome or *anywhere with anything* else I have control over, the metas are all in English and look fine... just the SERPs are screwed with.

When I view the site with various Google Bot agent strings via Chrome in hopes to emulate Google's view of the site, everything appears fine also - no problems at all with any meta fields.

There's no *visible* evidence of hacking directly on the site or in the WP database.  I don't see any rewriting or even watching for search engine bots that could manipulate these strings as they go into their databases.

Unfortunately Google takes some time to refresh its results so we're stuck with this until Google or Bing refreshes in terms of trial and error testing... but what's worse is there's no apparent way to reproduce seeing this problem.

Is there a way to either trigger / force Google & Bing to refresh immediately or some mechanism beyond browser agent string modification that could trigger this apparently very specific issue or response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has a tool called [fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) that is meant for this purpose.  Googlebot fetches the pages and shows you what it fetched.

Bing has an equivalent tool called [fetch as Bingbot](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/fetch-as-bingbot-fe18fa0d).

Answer (score 0):

Your site has been hacked. 
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked/fixing_the_japanese_keyword_hack

Good luck! -Susan